# Modify and Create Vector From Data Frame Character Column

Tags: r

Using the iris dataset in R, I am trying to create a new vector containing all the data points in column `Petal.Width`. While creating the new vector, I'd like to add 1 to each of the values of the `setosa` `Species`, but leave the other `Petal.Width` values the same.  I'm trying to use and if statement.

```
if(Species=="setosa"){
  Petal.Width+1
} else{
   (Petal.Width)
}
```

Warning message:

```
In if (Species == "setosa") { :   the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ifelse` instead

```
iris$petal_1 <- with(iris, ifelse(Species == "setosa", Petal.Width + 1, Petal.Width))
```

Answer (score 0):

The logical vector can be coerced to binary with `TRUE` representing 1 and `FALSE` as 0 when we add with a numeric column.  So, we don't need an `if/else` or `ifelse` condition.

```
with(iris, (Species == "setosa") + Petal.Width)
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that this is really an R question, not an Rstudio question.  The answer is the same regardless of which interface you use.

@danielanderson gave a good answer, here are a couple more for you to consider and hopefully learn from:

```
iris <- within(iris, petal_1= Petal.Width + ifelse(Species=='setosa', 1, 0))
iris$petal_1 <- iris$Petal.Width + ( iris$Species == 'setosa' )
iris[['petal_1']] <- iris$Petal.Width + c(1,0,0)[ iris$Species ]
```

Also look at `%in%` if you ever want to match any of a group rather than a single value.

Comment: Thank you. I'm new to all this. I've been working in RStudio, so I that's why I put it as an RStudio question